# Dot Net Framework Bootable

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-assembly

I would like to know if it is possible to create an assembly boot for the .Net framework that initiates the framework interpretation processes, so that I can start a visual basic application normally since the framework was processed in memory and initialized my application in visualbasic can automatically start directing in the assembly just like an operating system:

jmp 21h = assumed position of the framework.
jmp 00h = assumed position of visual basic application

I know it is not as simple as I wrote above is just an example, but following this reasoning when starting every framework my application will start normally ??

obs: obviously some command will not work for windows dependency and some functions also but not to have something functional with this that run small Visual Basic programs booting without operating system?

Comment: the whole .Net framework heavily depends on Windows OS services, so you have to provide these services first (by own OS or by windows and if by windows, they generally really dislike not being booted into exclusively (to the extend of damaging boot managers of other operating systems)). The Mono framework is more versatile (can work with different operating systems), but still it's tightly coupled with them and requires lot of common modern OS (or at least windows) functionality. "is it possible?" = yes, anything (math-feasible) is possible. "difficulty?" = probably years of development.

Comment: I'm just going to leave these here: [Cosmos OS](https://www.gocosmos.org/) & [IL2CPU](https://www.il2cpu.net/)

Comment: The .NET Framework has **nothing to do with VBA**. Please pay attention to the tag information when tagging a question and specify the correct programming language.